# How to use Powershell output in a pipeline

Tags: powershell

My purpose is to write some string into a file, and the file path is something like `%SystemDrive%\temp.txt`.  The pipeline looks like

```
 Write-Output "test" |  Out-File -FilePath %SystemDrive%\temp.txt
```

I can get `%SystemDrive%` by `(Get-ChildItem -Path Env:\SystemDrive).Value`, but how can I put it into the pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Join-Path` wrapped in parenthesis to set the `FilePath` for `Out-File`.

```
Write-Output "test" | Out-File -FilePath (Join-Path -Path (Get-ChildItem -Path Env:\SystemDrive).Value -ChildPath "\temp.txt")
```

The path that this yields on my system is:

```
C:\temp.txt
```

You can add the `-WhatIf` switch to the end of the command to see that it works, without actually writing the file.

Answer (score 0):

I'd opt for creating a temp folder on C then output the txt file to that folder.

Get-"something"|  Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\temp.txt